Upper bound on expectation of a convolution
Given probability densities $f, g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^3), \ \forall p\geq 1$, with the same first and second moments
\begin{align} & \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} v f(v)\,dv = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} v g(v)\,dv, \\[8pt] & \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |v|^2 f(v)\,dv = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |v|^2 g(v)\,dv,\end{align}
what bound can I get on
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |v-w|(f(w) - g(w)) \, dw \right|^2 f(v)\,dv\text{?}$$
I would like a bound in terms of $\|f-g\|_{L^p}$ for one of several different values of $p$, or in terms of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\log\left(\frac{f(v)}{g(v)}\right)f(v)\,dv$.
I am okay to assume existence of higher moments of $f, g$.
If I assume that either $f$ or $g$ is subgaussian, I can use weighted Pinsker's inequality but I would like to avoid this strong assumption.
